# 画面をダブルタップ時に設定した文字を音声再生したい

Tags: swift

swift というか、プログラミングを始めたばかりの初心者です。

画面をダブルタップ時に設定した文字（こんにちは）を音声で再生したいのですが、
再生されません。

AVFoundationフレームワークをインポートし、
Tap Gesture Recognizerを使いました。以下がコードです。
Recognizeは2Tapsにセットしています。

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "こんにちわ")


    @IBAction func tapView(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        synthesizer.speak(utterance)
    }

    @IBOutlet var double: UITapGestureRecognizer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

おそらく初歩的なことだと思うので申し訳有りませんが、
ご教授いただけたら助かります。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Simulatorを使っているなら、まず「hello」で発音するか確認してみてください。発音されたなら、使用言語がデフォルトの英語になっているだけの可能性があるので、SimulatorのHardwareのHomeでホームに戻って、SettingsのGeneralのLanguage & Regionで、iPhone Languageを日本語に設定してから試してみてください。

Comment: 意図せずアカウントが分かれてしまった場合は[「間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか?」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)をご覧下さい。